# Do empty delegates not get invoked?

Tags: .net, delegates, virtual-machine

In .NET, when you have a delegate that only has an empty method subscribed to it, does the .NET VM realize this and skip even calling it?

I'm asking because I noticed that the invocation count is set to 2 when you subscribe once but when you unsubscribe it, the value goes down to 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what you are seeing is the MulticastDelegate class optimizing the general case in which there's only *one* target method.  With just one, it can store the target in the base class' (Delegate) _methodBase and _target fields.

When there's more than one then it has to create a list to store the targets.  Now it uses its _invocationList field so it can store as many targets as needed.  In other words, _invocationCount will *never* be 1.

You can see this by expanding "base" in the debugger.

Comment: Ah, the joys of misinterpreting internal field values. Computing the invocation count via `GetInvocationList()` *does* return 1, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

No, an empty but non-null delegate will still be invoked as far as I'm aware.

Regarding your unsubscription: please provide some sample code. (I'll provide sample code showing the reverse in a minute.)

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action action = EmptyMethod;
        Console.WriteLine(action.GetInvocationList().Length);        
        action += NonEmptyMethod;
        action -= NonEmptyMethod;
        Console.WriteLine(action.GetInvocationList().Length);        
    }

    static void EmptyMethod() {}

    static void NonEmptyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing");
    }
}
```

This just prints 1 twice - showing a single "empty" handler before and after the subscribe/unsubscribe cycle.

I'm sure that when you've posted a similar example which shows what you mean, we'll be able to explain your results easily.

Comment: Skeeted once again :) ... congrats on the 200K - Inspirational.

Comment: @Gishu: I'm not at 200K just yet. Another 166 to go. I suspect that will happen tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

```
EventHandler del = null;
EventHandler subscriber2 = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2");};
del += delegate { };
Console.WriteLine(del.GetInvocationList().Length);
del += subscriber2;
Console.WriteLine(del.GetInvocationList().Length);

del(null, null);

del -= subscriber2;
Console.WriteLine(del.GetInvocationList().Length);
```

Output:

```
1
2
Subscriber2
1
```